# Unable to use GEM_HOME in radrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radrails

I have setup `Radrails` on my linux machine. I dont have root privileges on this machine and I also cant edit the ruby installation folder. I have set `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` to a location where I have privileges. I am running radrails from the terminal where I have set these variables. Does `Radrails` is  recognize the gem location?

Also I am not able to start the Webrick server using Radrails. The server always is in stopped state and the console output is blank. I am not able to fix this since I dont see any errors.

thank you!

Comment: you can just use rvm/rbenv, and install using one of them required rubies, then rails

Comment: I installed a VM and installed ruby, rails and radrails on it. It ran without issue. Thanks!

Comment: You've installed Vm or rvm?

Answer (score 0):

Use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) or [rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv) to change ruby and gem space to another one. If you will begin usage of the them do the following:

1. [Install `rvm`](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) with ruby:

   ```
   $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
   ```

   or [install `rbenv`](https://github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-insta), and then install ruby, and make it global:

   ```
   $ \curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
   $ rbenv install 2.1.4
   $ rbenv global 2.1.4
   ```
2. Install the [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) without documentation into the general gem space:

   ```
   $ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
   ```
3. Enter to the project, create two files `.ruby-version` with just installed version of `ruby` (in example `2.1.4`), and `.ruby-gemset` with name of your project:

   ```
   $ cd project-folder
   $ echo "2.1.4" > .ruby-version
   $ echo "your-project-name" .ruby-gemset
   ```
4. Fix `Gemfile` with newly intsalled version of `ruby` adding a line:

   ```
   ruby '2.1.4'
   ```
5. Reenter to the project folder, and `rvm` will generate its wrappers:

   ```
   $ cd .. ; cd project-folder
   ```
6. Issue gem installation:

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```